# C# Checking Same DOB & Different Name

Tags: c#

i would like to do some checking on this code regarding the duplicate DOB and different NAME. Somehow i was stuck in here not sure where to start with those condition checking whereby if the duplicate DOB and different name will be Logged to file.

```
public static bool ValidateDOB(string DOB, string EffDate, string PolicyNo, string Name)
        {
            bool var_return = true;

            string[] DOBSplit = DOB.Split('/');

            string var_Day = DOBSplit[0];
            string var_Month = DOBSplit[1];
            string var_Year = DOBSplit[2];

            string[] EffDateSplit = EffDate.Split('-');
            //string var_name = Name.ToString(); 

            //StreamWriter sb; 
            if (Convert.ToInt32(var_Day) <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt32(var_Year), Convert.ToInt32(var_Month)))
            {
                DateTime var_DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(var_Year + "-" + var_Month + "-" + var_Day);
                DateTime var_EffDateAsTodayDate = Convert.ToDateTime(EffDateSplit[2] + "-" + EffDateSplit[1] + "-" + EffDateSplit[0]);

                Int32 ActualAge = CalculateAge(var_DOB, var_EffDateAsTodayDate);

                if (ActualAge < 18 || ActualAge >= 60)
                {
                    var_return = false;

                    //sb = File.AppendText(var_LogFilePath + "-TESTING.log");
                    //InsertLogFile("Error - The Age is greater than 64 or below 18 (Actual Age: " + ActualAge + ", DOB: " + var_Day + "/" + var_Month + "/" + var_Year + ")");
                    LFC.writeTxtFile(var_LogFilePath, var_ErrorLogFilename + "_" + var_MinValue + "-" + var_MaxValue + ".log", "Error - The Age is greater than 60 or below 18 (Policy No: " + PolicyNo + ", Actual Age: " + ActualAge + ", DOB: " + var_Day + "/" + var_Month + "/" + var_Year + ")", true, true, false);
                }


            }
```

Comment: This is quite vague, what means _"somehow i was stuck in here "_? Also what does `CalculateAge`, it seems to be related, isn't it?

Comment: I mean im not sure where to start the condition checking. Kindly advise

Comment: It's not clear with what you want to compare it. You should provide a sample file. What should happen if there is a different name with the same day of birth?

Comment: There is only one DOB, which is passed as  `string` parameter to the method, so there cannot be a duplicate.  Similar for Name.  A little more context would be useful.  You can use the `string.Compare` method for both for the purpose of comparison, but you'll need data against which to compare them.

Comment: if different name and same day of birth thats mean wrong. the reason i put DOB is the main unique number for identification.

Comment: Since when has DOB been a suitable *unique* identifier? What kind of domain are you working in where it's impossible for two people to have the same DOB?

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding , it should be ID for unique identifier. May i know how to compare if duplicate ID and different name will be prompt error?